# WebAPI File Download

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, httpresponsemessage

I need to create a WebAPI method which downloads a file.  The file is being correctly downloaded, however the download seems to remain stuck at almost 100% percent in the client browser (ie it doesn't terminate although the file would have downloaded and can be opened).  It remains like that for a couple of minutes before terminating.  What could the problem be?  The following is some test code which replicates my issue

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetFile()
{
    string fileName = @"c:\temp\test.zip";

    MemoryStream responseStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (FileStream source = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open))
        source.CopyTo(responseStream);

    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response.Content = new StreamContent(responseStream);
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(ContentTypeHelper.Instance.GetFileContentType(fileName));
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
    response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = responseStream.Length;
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Remove `response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = responseStream.Length;` The `StreamContent` will set that based on the contained stream.

Comment: I tried adding that line to see if it would fix my issue but it didn't.  Before I didn't include it and it still didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to rewind the MemoryStream after copying:

```
MemoryStream responseStream = new MemoryStream();
using (FileStream source = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open))
    source.CopyTo(responseStream);
responseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```